# Pandas dataframe: simplest way to find arow and select an element from that row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

How can I get a column value from a row given that this row was found using another value form another column? For example:

```
row = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'john']
```

and now I would like to get his email with something like this `row['email']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. Note the below includes no error-handling. It's assumed the given name exists.

#### `pd.DataFrame.loc` + `pd.Series.values`

This accesses the underlying NumPy array and extracts the first item:

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'john', 'email'].values[0]
```

#### `pd.DataFrame.at`

Set your index to `Name`, then use `at`. Assumes your names are unique, otherwise scalar access in this way may not make sense.

```
df.set_index('Name').at['john', 'email']
```

If you do this often, I recommend you store `df.set_index('Name')` to avoid expensive repeat operations.

#### `pd.Series.loc`

Similar to the first solution but utilising `pd.Series` methods:

```
df['email'].loc[df['Name'].eq('john').index[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc` is a row and column indexer. So you can simply do

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'john', 'email']
```

Comment: But the result of this won't be the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.get_value` too if you have

syntax:

```
DataFrame.get_value(index, col, takeable=False)
```

Example

```
df.get_value(1, 'email')
```

Here one is the index of the row

or `df.at[]`

```
df.at[1, 'email']
```